# Naming of bit columns using the bitfield and an additional table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to organize the large amount of bit flags in the database. These flags are appearing often and I do not want to add columns when Customer wants to add one "very_important_is_active" flag in some tables where different objects are storing.
For example, I have the following code:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..#SomeKindOf') IS NULL 
BEGIN 
    CREATE TABLE #SomeKindOf(EntryID SMALLINT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, TickArray TINYINT DEFAULT 0 );
    INSERT INTO #SomeKindOf (TickArray)
        VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(19),(255),(15),(31),(7),(63),(127),(15),(38),(63),(17);
END 
SELECT  
    EntryID,
    CAST(IIF((1 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS FirstBit,
    CAST(IIF((2 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS SecondBit,
    CAST(IIF((4 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ThirdBit,
    CAST(IIF((8 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS FourthBit,
    CAST(IIF((16 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS FifthBit,
    CAST(IIF((32 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS SixthBit,
    CAST(IIF((64 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS SeventhBit,
    CAST(IIF((128 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS EighthBit,
    TickArray
FROM #SomeKindOf 

UPDATE #SomeKindOf SET TickArray = TickArray | 4 WHERE EntryID = 1

SELECT  
    EntryID,
    CAST(IIF((1 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS FirstBit,
    CAST(IIF((2 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS SecondBit,
    CAST(IIF((4 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ThirdBit,
    CAST(IIF((8 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS FourthBit,
    CAST(IIF((16 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS FifthBit,
    CAST(IIF((32 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS SixthBit,
    CAST(IIF((64 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS SeventhBit,
    CAST(IIF((128 & TickArray) > 0, 1, 0) AS BIT) AS EighthBit,
    TickArray
FROM #SomeKindOf WHERE EntryID = 1
```

OK, this works fine but I want to store in the table for example the following:

| Table | ColumnNo | ColumnName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Venue | 1 | Is Active |
| Venue | 2 | Is Closed |
| Venue | 4 | Is Important |
| Venue | 8 | Is Very Important |
| Venue | 16 | Is Outdated |
| City | 1 | Is Default |
| City | 2 | Is Recommend |
| City | 4 | Is Overpopulated |
| City | 8 | Is Abandoned |

And to link it when it needed for different objects to generate this array of ticks for the interface using the ColumnNo for bit shift and ColumnName for the alias of the result.

Is it possible? In which way it should be linked? 5 times for every Venue or it could be done in some more economy way?

Comment: Just give your bit columns proper names

Answer (score 0):

You can define the bits in one table and use them to pick apart collections of bits in another table by using `cross join` for each collection of bits to be decoded. The following code outputs one *row* for each set bit:

```
-- Define bits.
--   Note that the position is used, not a mask, to preclude multi-bit values.
declare @BitPositions as Table ( BitPosId Int Identity, Class VarChar(10), BitPosition Int, BitName VarChar(64) );
insert into @BitPositions ( Class, BitPosition, BitName ) values
  ( 'Attribute', 0, 'Active' ), ( 'Attribute', 1, 'With Laces' ),
  ( 'Attribute', 2, 'Lunch' ), ( 'Attribute', 3, 'Bright' );

-- Some sample data with assorted bits.
declare @Samples as Table ( SampleId Int Identity, Attributes Int /* , Zones Int */ );
insert into @Samples ( Attributes ) values
  ( 0 ), ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 4 ), ( 8 ), ( 16 ), ( 32 ), ( 13 ), ( 7 );

-- Pick the bits apart.
select S.SampleId, S.Attributes,
  BPA.BitPosId, BPA.BitPosition, BPA.BitName,
  -- Calculate the bit mask for the bit position: 2 ^ BitPosition.
  Power( 2, BPA.BitPosition ) as BitMask,
  -- Get the value of the bit from the sample data.
  Cast( Sign( S.Attributes & Power( 2, BPA.BitPosition ) ) as Bit ) as AttributeBitValue
  --, Cast( Sign( S.Zones & Power( 2, BPZ.BitPosition ) ) as Bit ) as ZoneBitValue
  from @Samples as S cross join
    -- Cross join with each set of bit definitions needed:
    @BitPositions as BPA -- cross join @BitPositions as BPZ
    where BPA.Class = 'Attribute' -- and BPZ.Class = 'Zone'
      -- Comment out the following line to see all of the bits.
      and Cast( Sign( S.Attributes & Power( 2, BPA.BitPosition ) ) as Bit ) = 1 -- Filter out only the set bits.
  order by S.SampleId, BPA.BitPosition;
```

If you need an unpredictable *column* for each bit then you could generate *dynamic SQL* to calculate the columns or pivot the query results. In any event, whatever consumes the result may be surprised by columns appearing or changing names.

Note: Bit masking gets *hinky* when you try to play with the most-significant bit of signed integer data types. Avoiding sign and overflow issues is possible, but a nuisance.

Adding *computed columns* to the table or creating a *view* are other approaches to adding columns based on existing data.